# What should I do if my iPod keeps saying "Connect to power"?

Tags: battery, ipod-nano

I have an iPod Nano (6th generation). I bought it 10 months ago. I fully charged it and it started to work. Since then, I left it 10 months without using nor charging. Now, when I connect it to PC, it charges, but after detaching from PC, it says 'Connect to power'. What is the problem? Is its battery damaged? What should I do?

Comment: Does it still say this after being connected for more then 15 or 20 minutes?

Comment: @bassplayer7 As I read the question, the iPod appears to charge when connected to the computer, but instantly dies when removed. If this is the case, it's pretty much a closed case that the battery has died.

Comment: Yes, I can see what you are saying. Agreed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it! there wasn't any problem with battery. just charged it with a charger (not with usb) and it started to work.

Answer (score 5):

The battery in your iPod has died. I suggest making an appointment at your local Apple Store Genius Bar and they may be able to replace it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my trusty iPod which I had plugged into my Audi's adapter. It worked perfect for years. I recently moved it to my new Audi (which no longer has a built in adapter).  Up came a message "connect to power" with a picture of a battery. Plugged into USB outlet on my car with a cord I had not used in years and no luck, then plugged into outlet in home with no luck.

My wife fixed it by using a cord from her older iPad. In short check your cord first.

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried to restore my 2004 20GB iPod Classic; and got the "plug in to power outlet" to complete the restore. The iPod was then stuck on this for 24 hours+ using a 30 pin - USB plugged into my Apple iPhone charger. What I did was connect it direct to a 2 gang with USB socket (in the UK) via an Amazon's Basics 30 pin - USB lead which my wife uses to charge her iPad2 - this immediately started charging the iPod. I seem to recall Apple going from 12v to 5v (or something like that) with the iPhone4(?) - so I'm guessing not enough juice was present to complete the restore process.

Anyway, hope that this might help someone.